# Какой язык учить для разработки приложений на Андроид - Kotlin или Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Какой язык стоит учить для разработки приложений на Андроид.

Kotlin или Java?

Пожалуйста, дайте дельный совет новичку.

Answer (score 2):

Оба. Kotlin является приоритетным языком программирования под Android. Об этом объявил Google на [Google IO 2019](https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/07/kotlin-is-now-googles-preferred-language-for-android-app-development/).

Почти везде весь новый код пишется на Kotlin (кроме очень уж старых легаси проектов).

При этом выучить Kotlin и забить на Java не получится. Есть несколько причин:

- Никто не отменял легаси код
- Вся документация до 2019 года написана на Java
- Зная Java перейти на Kotlin проблем не соствляет, а вот наоборот так не работает
- Kotlin основан на Java, а значит там работают почти все те же правила, что и в Java

Поэтому если вы выучите только Kotlin, то скорее всего вы не пройдете ни одного собеса. Если вы выучите только Java то вы потеряете более 50% потенциальных вакансий.

Поэтому рекомендую выучить Java. Как только перейдете на Android и будете уверенно чувствовать себя в Java - начинайте переходить на Kotlin.

Answer (score -2):

Для меня Kotlin по отношению к Java является синтаксическим сахаром как, например, CoffeeScript к JavaScript. Вряд ли можно освоить Kotlin до уровня, превышающего уровень знаний Java.

Зная Java, Kotlin можно освоить за несколько часов.

Мобильные проекты легко переводятся из Java в Kotlin. Для этого в Android Studio есть встроенный конвертер.

[image: Конвертирование код Java в код Kotlin]

Comment: Да, а Java это синтаксический сахар над C++. А если пойти дальше то assembler синтаксический сахар над двоичным кодом. Люди совершнествуют языки не просто так. Это делается для того, чтоб программисты могли меньше думать о деталях и решали более серьезные задачи. Условно ничего не мешает написать крутой UI на ассемблере, но только сколько на это времени уйдет и сколько ошибок будет. А этот самый "Синтаксический сахар" позволяет не делать глупую работу (которую уже делали другие миллион раз)

Comment: "Вряд ли можно освоить Kotlin до уровня, превышающего уровень знаний Java." Что это вообще значит?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что лучше изучить Java. Зная Java, Kotlin можно освоить за несколько часов. Перевести мобильные проекты из Java в Kotlin тоже очень лекго, для этого Android Studio обладает всеми инструментами.